# How to get access to whole internal memory from computer

Tags: backup

Is there a way to access a whole internal memory (with apks, apps data and others)? Because I must backup it, but a state of free space doesn't allow me to install any apps.

Comment: You are chasing the wrong problem... have you checked our insufficient storage tag info? http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info

Comment: Also see our [backup tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info). There are ways to initiate a full backup from PC without installing anything additional onto the Android device. And to partly answer the question you asked: not without rooting the device, no.

Comment: I have a rooted device